# How to trigger file type specific settings after they they have been executed in vimrc?

Tags: tab-characters

I have the following setting in my vimrc

```
autocmd FileType * setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

This is just so that every file I open looks consistent.

I also have another setting in after\ftplugin\make.vim

```
setlocal tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab
```

It looks like when I open `makefile` settings in make.vim are triggered first and that settings in vimrc are triggered last. Is there a way to make `make.vim` settings to be triggered last?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do `set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2`?   That will apply for all filetypes when put in your vimrc, unless an ftplugin overrides it.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add expandtab to the original code. I've just done the edit. That is what my concern. Expand the tabs in every file except when it is make.

Comment: As @EvergreenTree suggested, just put `set expandtab` in your vimrc and do not put `setlocal expandtab` in your FileType autocommand.

Comment: @EvergreenTree Can you post an answer so I could accept it and upvote it. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just directly put `set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2` in your vimrc.  That way it is the default, but it can be overridden ftplugins and anything in the `after` directory.  For more about how vim's runtime directories work, see `:help 'runtimepath'`.  Also, [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html) is a nice summary of what each directory does.